Issue with Bootstrap 4 collapses in pills tabs using Rails 6 and Haml
Context
I'm working on a Rails application using Bootstrap for the UI. I want to integrate a set of pills, each containing an accordion that displays a list of subcategories. When a subcategory is selected, a list of clickable skills should appear.
However, after introducing dynamic variables to allow closing a collapse when another one is opened, the collapses no longer display when I click on the links.
Question
How can I resolve this issue so that each collapse in the accordions works correctly with dynamic IDs
It worked when I didn't put a dynamic id on my accordion but as soon as I changed tabs the collapses no longer closed as expected, so I added one to my accordion and sub ids to my collapses but that didn't work. gave nothing

- master_category = SkillCategory.top_categories

%ul#pills-tab.nav.nav-pills.mb-3{role: "tablist"}

  - master_category.each_with_index do |category, index|
    %li.nav-item{role: "presentation"}
      %button{id: "pills-#{index}-tab", class: "nav-link #{index==0? 'active' : ''}", "aria-controls" => "pills-#{index}", "aria-selected" => (index == 0 ? "true" : "false"), "data-target" => "#pills-#{index}", "data-toggle" => "pill", role: "tab", type: "button"}= category.name

#pills-tabContent.tab-content
  - master_category.each_with_index do |category, index|

    -sub_categories = SkillCategory.where(master_category_id: category.id)
    -skills = CustomTag.where(category_id: category.id)

    .tab-pane.fade{id: "pills-#{index}", "aria-labelledby" => "pills-#{index}-tab", role: "tabpanel", class: index==0 ? 'show active' : ''}
      .d-flex.form-inline
        .form-group
          %input.form-control.mr-sm-2{"aria-label" => "Search", placeholder: "Search", type: "search"}
        %button.btn.btn-outline-success.my-2.my-sm-0{type: "submit"} Search

      - if sub_categories.present?
        %div{id: "accordion-#{category.id}"}
          - sub_categories.each_with_index do |sub_category, sub_index|
            .card
              .card-header{id: "#heading-#{index}-#{sub_index}"}
                %h5.mb-0
                  %button.btn.btn-link.w-100.d-flex.justify-content-between.align-items-center.font-weight-bold{"data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target" => "#collapse-#{index}-#{sub_index}", "aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-controls" => "#collapse-#{index}-#{sub_index}"}
                    = sub_category.name
                    %span.fa.fa-plus
              .collapse{id: "collapse-#{index}-#{sub_index}", class: "ml-4", "aria-labelledby" => "heading-#{index}-#{sub_index}", "data-parent" => "#accordion-#{category.id}"}
                .list-group.list-group-flush.checkbox-list-group
                  - CustomTag.where(category_id: category.id).each do |skill|
                    .list-group-item
                      %label
                        %input{type: "checkbox"}/
                        %span.list-group-item-text
                          %i.fa.fa-fw
                          = skill.name

      - elsif skills.present?
        .list-group.list-group-flush.checkbox-list-group
          - skills.each do |skill|
            .list-group-item
              %label
                %input{type: "checkbox"}/
                %span.list-group-item-text
                  %i.fa.fa-fw
                  = skill.name

  %button.btn.btn-hacktiv.btn-rounded.btn-plain.d-inline-block{name: "button", type: "submit"}= t("views.various.validate")

- content_for :bottom_styles do
  = c_style_partial_render("forms.css")


